# Empty y-axes label in tikzpicture-diagram

Tags: pgfplots

I'm searching for to code for a empty y-axis label. I don't want numbers on my y-axis. Any Ideas?

My code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[only marks, width=1.02\textwidth,height=0.2\textheight,
        legend style={at={(1,1)},xshift=-13.25cm, yshift=-0.1cm,anchor=north west,nodes=left},

            xtick={1700, 1725, 1750, 1775, 1800, 1825, 1850, 1875, 1900, 1925, 1950, 1975}, %=Intervals
            x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=}, 
            y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
            %extra y ticks={456.1, 1022.4},
            %extra y tick labels={{456,1},{1022,4}},
            extra y tick style={grid=major,
                tick label style={, ,}},
                ymin=0.7,
                ymax=1.4,
            ylabel={Phänomenbelege},
            enlarge x limits=0.01]  

            \addplot  table [x=jahr, y=bla] {bla.txt};
            \addplot  table [x=jahr, y=blub] {blub.txt};
                        \legend{bla, blub} 
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi Leah, welcome to the site! You can get rid of the tick labels using `ytick=\empty`. If for some reason that doesn't work for you, feel free to edit your question with additional information.

Comment: Great! didn't thought it is that easy!thanks for your quick answer.